# Raspberry Pi4 Uart Receive Buffer Overflow

Tags: uart

i have a device which is streaming via usb2serial to ttyUSB0 on my pi4. I use the Baudrate 345600 but I looks like I loose data in between. Does anybody know something about the receive uart buffer? Is there a way to detect a buffer overflow? Or could I increase or set a bigger uart buffer?

Thanks!

Comment: You may mitigate issue by trying to dedicate a CPU for this. You need to setup IRQ affinity that your CPU will serve only USB interrupts and nothing  more. How many CPU cores Pi4 has? Two? But all this sounds strange. Are you really talking about USB?

Comment: In case you are talking about real UART, you should know that modern CPUs in modern OSes may not be so quick to serve UART. I understand it’s not so obvious. Technically mitigation is as above — reduce IRQ latency. Also you may need to disable power management.